# onCharacteristicChanged getting called multiple times without change in Characteristic values

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I'm developing an android bluetooth low energy app where I'm getting data from a peripheral device in a single characteristic. I have enabled notifications on this characteristic and process characteristic value inside `onCharacteristicChanged` method. But this method gets called multiple times even if the characteristic value doesn't change. I put logs inside this method and noticed that the program enters this method atleast 4-5 times. I had the perception that this method will get called only when there is an update in Characteristic value. Why is it getting called multiple times?

Comment: The characteristic has been re-measured but just happens to be the same as the last time is the most likely scenario.  It will depend what it's meant to represent.